# How can I make property comparison able to be compiled to SQL expression in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

There are two tables that one column of table A is pointing another table B's primary key.

But they are placed in different database, so I cannot configure them with foreign key.

Configuring via `relationship()` is unavailable, so I implemented property attribute manually.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BigInteger, id_seq, primary=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(256))


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    __bind_key__ = 'another_engine'
    # I am using custom session configures bind
    # each mappers to multiple database engines via this attribute.

    id = Column(BigInteger, id_seq, primary=True)
    author_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False, index=True)
    body = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)

    @property
    def author(self):
        _session = object_session(self)
        return _session.query(User).get(self.author_id)

    @author.setter
    def author(self, user):
        if not isinstance(user, User):
            raise TypeError('user must be a instance of User')
        self.author_id = user.id
```

This code works well for simple operations. But it causes dirty queries making SQLAlchemy's features meaningless.

Code would be simple if it was configured via `relationship()` (e.g. `query.filter(author=me)`) got messed up(e.g. `query.filter(author_id=me.id)`).

Relationship(e.g. join) related features are never able to be used in query building.

Can I use property attribute, at least, in building query criterion(`filter()/filter_by()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still use relationship here.  If you stick to "lazy loading", it will query for the related item in database B after loading the lead item in database A.  You can place a ForeignKey() directive in the Column, even if there isn't a real one in the database.   Or you can use primaryjoin directly:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(BigInteger, id_seq, primary=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(256))


class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    __bind_key__ = 'another_engine'

    id = Column(BigInteger, id_seq, primary=True)
    author_id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False, index=True)
    body = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)

    author = relationship("User", 
                primaryjoin="foreign(Article.author_id) == User.id")
```

Comment: Oh Thanks! join/joinedload cannot be used because of compiled query will be executed in single database engine which is mapped for executing query's primary mapper. but accessing relationship property, using it in filtering expression are working amazingly!